# Регулярное выражение для разделения блока строк

Tags: регулярные-выражения, vba

Есть текст:

[image: Строка]

Нужно разделить его на блоки между длинными горизонтальными разделителями. 
Пытался так:

```
[^\_]+
```

но прихватывает единичные "_".

[image: Ошибочное прихватывание]

Answer (score 0):

Используйте

```
^(?!_+$).+(?:(?:\r\n?|\n)(?!_+$).*)*
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/9YV0PF/2). Обязательно установите `regex.Multiline = True`.

- `^` - начало строки...
- `(?!_+$).+` - до конца которой не могут быть одни знаки подчеркивания
- `(?:(?:\r\n?|\n)(?!_+$).*)*` - 0 и более повторов

  - `(?:\r\n?|\n)(?!_+$)` - перевод строки, после которого следует строка, не состоящая целиком из `_`
  - `.*` - 0 и более символов, отличных от знаков перевода строки.